# Creating a project that only uses Symfony2's Console Component

Tags: symfony, console, components, command-line-interface

How can I create a new project that only uses the Symfony2 Console component?

I haven't been able to figure out the most basic setup I would need to do, to just use the Console component (and any other must-have dependencies).

Where should I place the component files, and what do I need to include in my own code file?

The online tutorials are seriously lacking in detailed step by step explanations on how to use the various components as stand-alone components, and not as a part of the Symfony standard distribution.

**Solution Found:**

I've created a detailed step-by-step guide on how to use the [Symfony 2 Console Component](http://talater.com/symfony_console_component/) in your project. I hope this helps fill the documentation void.

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step guide, it's pretty useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one of the easiest ways would be to use [`Composer`](http://packagist.org/). Youd set up a `composer.json` in the root of your project and then just invoke `composer.phar install` from the command line.

Example composer.json for console:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/console": "2.*"
    }
}
```

After that you can just include the composer autoloading and you should be good to go.

```
// in your bootstrap or what have you
require 'path/to/project/root/vendor/.composer/autoload.php';
```

That jsut gets everything set up and ready to use though... you still need to figure out how to integrate it in a way that makes sense within your project. You might actually take a look at Composer itself or Doctrine 2 for some idea of how to do that since they both use it as their console interface.

Also just some validation... you arent the only one annoyed by the lack of documentation on using the standalone components outside the full stack. :-)

Comment: Composer will do the job well. I suggest reading the dedicated documentation of this component (which is quite new, you may not have seen it already): http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html. You can choose between the ClassLoader component or the composer autoload.php to autoload the files.

Comment: After almost giving up on composer because running `php composer.phar install` didn't do anything, I finally tried running it without the php at the beginning (`composer.phar install`) and it worked like a charm. Too bad the docs on the composer site insist on calling `php composer.phar`

Comment: I still wish I figured out how to do it with the ClassLoader, and no composer, like @Nanocom suggested, but I haven't been able to configure it correctly. Any suggestions? Do you know where I can see a sample project with just the ClassLoader, and maybe another module... Without all the cruft of the entire framework around it.

Comment: Hmm ive never had that issue with Composer before on OS X (10.5 - 10.7)... As far as a better example of console usage, no i dont have a better example.

Comment: To use the ClassLoader component: in your front controller, require 'path/to/UniversalClassLoader.php'; Then create an autoload.php file looking similar to this one: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/autoload.php (from standard edition), include it in your front controller too. And you're done.

Comment: And read the dedicated documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html